# Is android.permissions.FLASHLIGHT required to use Camera Flash?

Tags: android, permissions, camera, flashlight

For instance, [cardio library](https://www.card.io/) library uses camera flash, but doesn't require this permission.

I have test app using camera flash w/o this permission on Galaxy S2 (4.03) and Nexus One (2.3.6) and it went smoothly.

Does anybody has any experience with situations where you need **android.permissions.FLASHLIGHT** ? What is it used for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3079610/735675 check this.

Comment: 1 .The project referred from that link is no longer at code.google.com
2. It is a suggestion to research into the permission.. which, frankly, I did for an hour before asking this question.