# What permission I need in order to use camera flash in camera preview?

Tags: android, android-camera

I have a custom camera application and I need to be able to turn flash on(torch mode actually)/off.

What kind of permission do I need in this case?

1.Only

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

2.
Those from 1 plus:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
     android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
     android:protectionLevel="normal"/>
```

I think this is used when you want to use Flash, but without camera (like in this case: [Android - Using Camera Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079458/android-using-camera-flash/3079610#3079610))

3.Those from 1 plus:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"/>
```

**EDITED** (thanks to @maclir):

Above line is incorrect. The correct one is:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

developer.android.com: "Subfeature. The application uses the device camera's flash."  (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)

In all 3 cases, tested on 2 devices, works ok - I can activate/deactivate flash, but I want to be sure what exactly each of them means.
It is weird that even without option 3 it is working ok...for what is than used option 3?

I think I'm missing something...

**ANSWER**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

is mandatory in order to use the camera  (I'm not using camera via Intent, I have a customize camera app)

and:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />
```

are the camera specific features I use in the app.

`android:required="false"` means Google Play will **not** prevent the application from being installed to devices that do not include these camera features - so the user having a device without camera and camera flash will be able to install the app from market.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: I think option 3 is used best for the use of camera and autofocus.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/data/etc/android.hardware.camera.flash-autofocus.xml

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to android developers [permission-group](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-group-element.html):

> Note that this element does not declare a permission itself, only a category in which permissions can be placed. See the `<permission>` element for information on declaring permissions and assigning them to groups

You would need two permissions [Manifest.permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
```

to be able to access the camera and the flashlight.

And you would need to declares the hardware features that is used by the application (camera and flash) [Features Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#features-reference):

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />
```

`android:required` indicates whether phones not having these hardware can install your application or not.

On your third point, I think you have a type because `uses-permission` tag can not be used with `android.hardware...`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"/>
```

Comment: i've corrected in the question the third statement (actually added a comment) :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've updated the question to reflect better the answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Maclir** answer is showing all the detail of permission required to use  camera and its flash light. you can also use these two permission to use flashlight in your application.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: so, I do not need `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"/>` if I use `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />`  ?

Comment: in fact, if you add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>, it will implicitly add all the uses-features related with the camera..