# Application crashes in Samsung Grand Quatro Duos when trying to take picture programatically in android from front camera

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-camera2

I have tried to implement the code for taking picture programatically in Android using front camera from source available [on github](https://github.com/pharitz/de.vogella.camera.api/tree/master/src/de/vogella/camera/api).

The source code works fine on other devices like Micromax, Lenovo, but when I tried to test on Samsung Galaxy Grand Quatro Duos, the application crashed saying that:

> **takePicture failed at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method) at
>   android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1194)**

Can anyone help me about this issue? Moreover the camera class is deprecated over Api 21 Lollipop and I have to implement the same code using Camera2 API; if anyone knows how to implement the same using Camera2 API please post code or reference link.

Comment: see this ans http://stackoverflow.com/a/17576873/4146722

Comment: this solution doesnt work even i have the mentioned permission in the link @  PräTîk Tank